# Trying to pin box a dynamic writer to pass it across FFI with no luck in RUST

Tags: rust

I seem to have a basic problem that I can't solve.

I have this struct that expects apinned dynamic writer to pass to "C" and then later gets it back as a part of a callback function:

Here is the struct:

```
pub struct ExecutionContext<'a> {
    pub log: Pin<&'a mut Box<dyn std::io::Write>>,
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to pass a simple stderr to this struct though.

If I try

```rust
let mut stderr2 = Pin::new (&mut Box::<dyn Write>::new(stderr()));
```

I get this error:

```
function or associated item cannot be called on `Box<dyn std::io::Write>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
```

When I try this:

```rust
 let mut stderr2 = Pin::new (&mut Box::new(stderr()));
 let mut ctx = ExecutionContext{
     log: stderr2,
 };
```

I get :

```
expected trait object `dyn std::io::Write`, found struct `Stderr`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error continues with:

> the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `dyn std::io::Write: Sized`

The problem is that somehow calling `Box::new` with this type bounds requires the inner value of the `Box` to have a known size. Trait objects cannot provide that.
You can avoid that by creating explicitly a variable with your type annotations.

```rust
let mut b: Box<dyn Write> = Box::new(stderr());
let stderr2 = Pin::new(&mut b);
let mut ctx = ExecutionContext { log: stderr2 };
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5802922f8bf4b4e2c7667419298be85)

But may I ask for the reason of putting a Box behind a mutable reference?
Isn't a `Box` enough?

If you are willing to change the type of `ExecutionContext::log` I would recommend the following:

- store the `Box` directly behind the `Pin` in `ExecutionContext::log` (without the reference)
- use `Box::pin`, a constructor which creates a `Pin<Box<T>>` for you

```rust
pub struct ExecutionContext {
    pub log: Pin<Box<dyn std::io::Write>>,
}

let stderr2 = Box::pin(stderr());
let mut ctx = ExecutionContext { log: stderr2 };
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f42eb0eae4b5a1b79036425e1c1a8b1)

Comment: Thanks for the response. One of the first things I did was to use Pin<Box<T>>. The problem that I faced there was that in my case I first store ExecutionContext as *mut ExecutionContext inside a C pointer. Later on when I dereference it and try to use the logger let mut exec_ctx =   Box::from_raw(sapi_globals.server_context as *mut ExecutionContext);  exec_ctx.log.write(buf); I get cannot borrow data in a dereference of `Pin<Box<dyn std::io::Write>>` as mutable error.

Comment: You may check this sample here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1ff84c936656f71e3d6a3177f0f6b075 Without the pin it will work without any error but when there is pin it doesn't let me borrow it as_mut

Comment: I don't have much experience with ffi / unsafe: What is the reason for using `Pin` here? Probably you could remove it and it'll work. (ref: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/dtvmue/c_interface_via_ffi_works_only_if_struct_doesnt/ )